# How does additional assumptions increase approximation factor?

Tags: graphs, greedy-algorithms, matching

I am studying the greedy algorithm for maximal weighted matching in arbitrary graphs. I have proven that this algorithm has approximation factor $\frac{1}{2}$.

Assume now that the weights in the graph are such that if $W = ⟨w_1, w_2, \ldots , w_{|E|}⟩$ is the weights sorted in increasing order, then $w_i \leq cw_{i+1}$ for all $i \in \{1, 2,\ldots , |E| − 1\}$ with $0 < c \leq 1$. I believe that the approximation factor should increase when $c$ gets smaller, and I would like to express the approximation factor as a function of $c$. I have tried finding the approximation factor when $c = \frac{3}{4}$ but have not done much progress.

Any help would be very much appreciated:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that greedy approach should consider edges in weight decreasing order only.

> Otherwise it may become much less optimal, getting approximation factor as low as $c^{2n/3}$.

Then every edge $e_0$ of greedy matching may block up to two edges $e_1$ and $e_2$ of maximum weight matching. However since $e_0$ is taken by greedy approach, then $w(e_0) > w(e_1)$ and $w(e_0) > w(e_2)$. WLOG $w(e_1) > w(e_2)$, then $w(e_1) \le c w(e_0)$ and $w(e_2) \le c w(e_1) \le c^2 w(e_0)$. Therefore maximum weight of a matching is at most $\max\{\,1, c + c^2\,\}$ times greater than the weight of greedy matching. So the approximation factor is $\frac{1}{\max\{\,1, c + c^2\,\}} = \min\{\,1, \frac{1}{c + c^2}\,\}$. For $c = \frac 34$ it equals to $\frac{16}{21}$. Note that for $c \le \frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}2$ greedy approach gives an optimal solution.